# How make elements in table th be in line in DateRangePicker

Tags: css, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I looked for a way to align elements inside *th* to fix daterange picker look

[image]

I tried to add *display:flex", "display: inline-block", but those weren't working

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way using **float** property to be added to inner select elements:
Therefrom my final customized-daterangepicker.css looks like:

```
.daterangepicker table.table-condensed thead tr th.month select.monthselect {
    float: left
}

.daterangepicker table.table-condensed thead tr th.month select.yearselect{
    float: right;
}
```